# ExtJS, is it thread-safe?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, extjs, thread-safety

i use a variable to limit the query operation of users,just like the critical area of OS。

```
//call 'fun' only if it is free(at the end of fun ,it will do isQuery=true)
var getInfo= function(param,callback){
    if(!isQuery){   
     isQuery = true;
     fun(param,callback);
    }
}
```

but when two query requests happened at the same time, the `param` went wrong ,like A recieved `param` of B while B didn't call fun successfully! I think it is a multithreading problem,

When  A was authorized (`isQuery == false`) to call 'fun',and just before the sentence '`fun(param,callback)`' was going to execute, B called `getInfo` ,and passed new `param` and `callback` to `getInfo`,but now,`isQuery == true`, B is not authorized,then `getInfo` tured to execute fun`(param,callback)` with B's arguments,so it went wrong,i'm right?

ps: please forgive my poor english...

ps2:thank you very much,but i still feel unsure, maybe it is not a multithreading problem,but how does that happen?there is only one instance of 'getInfo',so will it always keep the latest argument?

Comment: JS runs in one thread in all browsers but chrome http://www.sitepoint.com/multi-threading-javascript/

Comment: I guess it is more about 'request-safety' than thread safety

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124764/are-mutexes-needed-in-javascript/124832#124832) I believe is the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the example is not enough to solve the problem and the problem is probably not related to Ext JS at all. Please provide the full source code.

What you have here is probably a common Javascript mistake with a double entering function with an inner function like this

```
    function broken(url, x) {

        var params = { something : x }

        function post() {
            $("#elem).get(url, params);
        }   

        post();

    }
```

broken() keeps only **one params state inside** it and delegates this to closures. Because you enter the function twice, when the initial params state is still being used, the first params state gets overridden.

To work around the problem o nly pass function parameters forward as is, do not create var locals in functions which may be double-entered.