# jQuery/AJAX concurrent access to global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, concurrency, thread-safety

I'm writing some jQuery code that performs a plain ajax call. I've a global Javascript variable that I need to increase **thread-safely** with every call. If this was Java, I would use `synchronized` but this is not the case :-)

Here's a code snippet:

```
var myval;

function myFunc()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: myurl,
        type: 'GET',
        data: { ...my data... },
        success: function()
        {
            myval++;
        }
    });
}
```

Given that `myFunc()` is associated with a click event, how can I be sure that `myvar` is always safely/consistently increased? I know I could *maybe* use `async: false`, but I'd prefer to avoid it. I'm not even sure it would work that way.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `everything that happens in an event must be finished before the next event will be processed`, from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124764/are-mutexes-needed-in-javascript :)

Comment: since AJAX is asynchronous by design, I think subsequent calls would read the variable's wrong value.

what if I start a call by clicking button A, then *before the first call is finished* I click button B? I can't predict how long each call will take to complete.

Comment: thanks @ProblemFactory, I'm reading it

Comment: @godzillante I wouldn't say it's "asynchronous by design" as such, more just "event driven with a single thread".  Event happens, code runs, browser twiddles its thumbs until the next event happens, repeat ad infinitum.  The code while it's running cannot be interrupted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no problem - JS doesn't suffer atomicity problems since there are no (user-visible) threads[*]

*Nothing* happens in JS except in response to an event or initial script load.  It's impossible for a piece of code to misread `myval` during an increment, because the entire `success` callback must complete before any other event handling code can start.

[*] Yes, there's WebWorkers, but they use message passing not variable sharing.